# AWS SSM PingStatus - Connection Lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have a running instance as a node on fleet manager. For the last days, I have a message under SSM pingStatus that tells **Connection Lost**.

I checked the documentation, and it tells to update the SSM agent via ssh commands. However, I can't access the instance via SSH, there's no way to access the instance.

Is there a way to solve this issue without destroying the node - instance ?

Comment: Why you can't ssh? Do you have keypair for the instance and when you try to login, you get an error?

Comment: @Riz yes I do have a keypair for the instance. But I can't ssh to the machine. It goes on a timeout

Comment: If you have a key pair then you can use PuTTY to access that machine